# Perfmon ASP.Net Apps "Sessions Active" Counter

Tags: asp.net, session, perfmon

EDIT: We realise that the sessions we're reviewing at the moment are inproc, and that's absolutely fine. The question, in a nutshell, is are the sessions active as reported in the inproc counter reliable as they are delivered? Or can they look higher than they actually are for any reason (I read a piece about it appearing to be in the region of 400 million or something due to the installation of ASP.Net 3.5 but I'm not talking that high).

At my place of work we're trying to ascertain how many people have an active session on a moment to moment basis as the number of active sessions is the trigger for a piece of load balancing software that activates an appliance. We're looking at the Asp.Net Apps "Sessions Active" Counter and it seems to be giving some slightly odd readings when we compare how many people appear to be browsing our site versus how much business we're actually doing. It is possible, for example, to register only 1600 active sessions but be selling items roughly every two minutes or, like this morning, to top 3000 active sessions but only be making sales every 15 minutes.

It is entirely possible that we just have a lot of lurkers but to be sure I wondered if anyone knew how this counter actually arrived at its figures and whether it is susceptible to any kind of false positive behaviour. I've been keeping an eye on the perfmon figures for a couple of hours now and the sessions active has veered between 3100 and 2700 but in all that time we've made about ten actual sales. Should we be taking it as gospel that we just have a lot of browsers?

Comment: Wil you mention which session mode are you using in your application? Thank you! ;)

Comment: Why, what difference would that make?

Comment: A good one: if it's in-process, if IIS app pool is recycled, IIS is reseted, or even Windows is rebooted, in any case, session won't survive, while SQL Server or State Server (or a custom one) will recover sessions after any of these actions.

Comment: I assume from having a quick look that I am talking about the InProc sessions, if inproc is the default, no one has ever changed it off that.

Comment: We don't have a problem with the sessions being InProc. We don't necessarily need them to survive the actions you describe.

Comment: Read my answer :) You'll find why you need to "survive" after these actions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming you're using In-Process session-state mode, first of all, I'd like to suggest you to switch to SQL Server or State Server modes since it seems you need a good active sessions' tracking.

As I stated in a comment in your answer...

> If it's in-process, if IIS app pool is
>   recycled, IIS is reseted, or even
>   Windows is rebooted, in any case,
>   session won't survive, while SQL
>   Server or State Server (or a custom
>   one) will recover sessions after any
>   of these actions.

... by using suggested modes, you'll be able to code some session tracking since, for example, SQL Server mode stores sessions in some table that can be queried in order to be sure what's going and in real-time.

I've no experience with State Server and I don't know how to retrieve sessions from it but it should be possible.

Speaking about SQL Server mode, I successfully could do scheduled maintenance so I could drop phantom sessions, check actual sessions which did some action last X minutes (meaning they're active...), and so on.

Comment: Hi, yeah, I guess if we ever really need to "review" real-time sessions another mode would be better. However what we are really concerned with is "are in-proc sessions really real or do they artificially inflate for any reason?" Thanks for this though, it is a useful thing to know.

Comment: Well, think a session is started for every web request that didn't have a session associated to it. Since some app pool recycling or some other action can vary active sessions, from a second to another you can have 30k active sessions and later 0, after another second 4k and so on. That's why I'm suggesting a more reliable way of handling sessions :D

Comment: We don't get that at all, actually it's fairly steady. Just, a little higher than we'd expect sometimes. It's literally a difference of ~1000 sessions deviation from what we'd expect given the amount of business being done. So nothing computationally,  but a lot statistically.

Comment: I did my best haha, you'll find that there's no reliable way of counting sessions using in-process mode.

Comment: No this is a good answer, except, why are inproc numbers unreliable? Is it just that they're susceptible to app pool refreshes, iis restarts and windows reboots? If so we like that answer, those are all things we can get a handle on. If there's anything else that might make them unreliable you know of that would be helpful to know.

Comment: For me, this is unreliable enough: it's very hard to track in small time intervals how many sessions are "active". Well, you know InProc won't allow you to know when was the latest request for some session, and other details like this that would be extremly useful if you want to track "active sessions". Counting active sessions in Session_Open/Abandon is based on how many requests with some session identifiers are returning to the web, but what happens if app pool is recycled or app has some error? Counter is dropped and session count can vary overtime and you end with incorrect values.

Comment: I understand but I guess it's all about what your purpose is. We have never really experienced a problem of dropped sessions but we don't want the number to be artificially inflated. So that's good enough for us. Besides, if we ever do get complaints about people's sessions randomly disappearing we have an instant suspect. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem and thanks for your vote, I appreciate it! :) I believe your counting problems should be in this way, that's why I suggested that, but there's no human way of knowing an exact reason without analyzing your code. Keep doing and good luck.